# Preferred org.slf4j on WebLogic 12c

Tags: slf4j, logback, weblogic12c

We have developed an J2EE app that usually is deployed on JBoss servers. We have also implementations on WebLogic 10.
We have migrated it to WebLogic 12c (specifically we run it on 12.1.2.). The migration would be a success if not for a small glitch – we do not see application log files. We use log4j and logback. 
I have added the parameter
-Dlogback.configurationFile=/logback.xml
to the WebLogic starting script.
I tried several approaches but to no avail.
1.  I defined:

```
<wls:container-descriptor><br>
    <wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>true</wls:prefer-web-inf-classes><br>
</wls:container-descriptor>
```

in weblogic.xml.
During deploy I get: Neither  nor  can be specified when  is turned on in weblogic.xml
though I have not specified these tags.
2.  I defined:

```
<wls:prefer-application-packages>
    <wls:package-name>org.slf4j</wls:package-name>
</wls:prefer-application-packages>`
```

in weblogic.xml
I get java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.Logger during deploy.
If I add these libraries to WEB-INF/lib I get:
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "com.comarch.cci.log.LogOutput.getLogger(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/slf4j/Logger;" the class loader (instance of weblogic/utils/classloaders/ChangeAwareClassLoader) of the current class, com/comarch/cci/web/utils/CciServletContextListener, and the class loader (instance of weblogic/utils/classloaders/GenericClassLoader) for resolved class, com/comarch/cci/log/LogOutput, have different Class objects for the type utput.getLogger(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/slf4j/Logger; used in the signature ./startWebLogic
3.  Using the admin console I checked:
Servers/AdminServer/Logging/General/Advanced "Redirect stderr logging enabled"
which allows me to see INFO logs in AdminServer.log
Could anyone tell me what I am missing and how to tell WebLogic to use my instance of slf4j?

Comment: It should be `org.slf4j.*`. The error message means you still have two versions on your classpath. What is your full weblogic.xml? Have you checked for dupe versions of the class in WEB-INF/lib ?

Comment: It does not matter. `org.slf4j.*` gives the same exception. And, of course I have two versions of slf4j.jar. 1.6.1 that is loaded by WebLogic and 1.6.4., which I specified to use in my app.

Comment: Ok, then you probably have 3 versions on your classpath, one coming from a location you haven't noticed yet. =)